# Knockout binding for isdirty functionality

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have to check whether there is any change on view or not.Here I am not able to bind form with model.

The code of my view page is:--

```
<section>
    <ul class="breadcrumb" role="menu">
        <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <a href="#">Home</a><span class="divider"></span></li>
        <li class="active"><i class="fa fa-office"></i> <span>Company</span></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12" data-bind="event:{change:dirty}">
            <div data-bind="tabs:{widgetData:widgetData}"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

and the part of code which I have written to check isDirty is:--

```
var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        canDeactivate: canDeactivate,       
        dirty: function (root) {
            var _initialized;
            var result = ko.computed(function () {
                if (!_initialized) {
                    ko.toJS(root);
                    _initialized = true;
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });

            return result;
        },
    };

 function canDeactivate() {
        if (vm.dirty == true) {
            var app = require('durandal/app');
            return app.showMessage('Are you sure you want to leave this page?', 'Navigate', ['Yes', 'No']);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: My question is,how to bind form with model that i can check whether  it is dirty or not while any change in form.

Answer (score 1):

The way to tell if a view has changed is to use the event binding.  I'm not entirely sure from your code which element you wish to check but you can easily put the change binding on an element to call dirty when the element changes

```
data-bind="event: {change: dirty}
```

this will call the dirty function each time the element value changes

the ko event binding documentation is located [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html)